# Use icomoon with link_to and icon_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, icons, font-face

I'm trying to move from Font Awesome to icomoon.

With Icomoon I can get the icons to work using the following syntax

```
<a href="#"><span data-icon="&#xe02b;" aria-hidden="true"></span>Some Text</a>
```

However, as I'm using a rails app I'd really prefer to use the following syntax, or something similar.

```
<%= link_to icon_tag("icon-pdf", "some text"), controller_path %>
```

I have tried the following as well, all to no avail

```
<%= link_to 'Some text', controller_path, {"data-icon" => "&#xe02b;", "aria-hidden" => "true"} %>
```

It doesn't matter if I put the defined name (icon-pdf) or its hex value in there, but I can't seem to get the icon to appear.

Is there a way I can achieve this, or am I stuck with the data-icon method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<%= link_to controller_path do %>
  <span data-icon="&#xe02b;" aria-hidden="true">Some Text</span>
<% end %>
```

Or

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, 'Some Text', :data_icon => "&#xe02b;", :aria-hidden => "true" ), controller_path %>
```

It should work. Thanks